# Android Voip in Sipdroid

Tags: android, voip, sipdroid

I followed [Sipdroid tutroial](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/) to make Voice call using VOIP based SIP account:

Sipdroid Call ends in 4 secs.

I have used [Pbxes](https://www1.pbxes.com/index_e.php) account created an extension,route and SIP account.

But i can get the calling screen.But the call is not connected.

When i connect to other numbers which has sipdroid call ends in 4 secs.

Answer (score 0):

Spidroid worked out with Pbxes.org.

We need to dial the extension number of the other device in which we installed spidroid.

Not the mobile numbers.

Now im trying with Freepbx.org.

I have installed freepbx in server.

But registration failed with Freepbx.